# catch text field event with command name in pythoncard

Tags: python, python-2.7, pythoncard

I am generating a text field component dynamically with the below code

```
widgetDefn = {'type':'TextField',
              'name':'somename',
              'font': {'style': 'bold', 'faceName': u'Arial','size': 9,'foregroundColor':(0, 0, 255)},
              'text':'',
              'position': (xPosWidget, yPos),
              'command':'takeaction',
              'foregroundColor':(7, 26, 248),
              'size': (30,20)
              }
```

In this name of TextField will vary so i can not do any action functionality with name so i want do or i want call function with command as `def on_takeaction_command(self, event):
        print "Event on text field",`
But it is working,on command function is working for type Button.Please help me how can i call Textfield command function.Thanks in advance.